# Link all .obj files from another project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-c++, msbuild

I have an executable C++ project that used to contain embedded unit tests. I've moved the tests to another (.dll) project, to use them with the VS Test Runner, and all is well except for a bunch of unresolved external symbol errors.

Things seem to work if I link all of the .obj files from the .exe into the .dll, but there are a lot of them and it's very "dirty" to hardcode them since the list can always change.

I've tried adding the .exe project as a reference and setting "use Library Dependency Inputs" to True, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: So now you have 2 exes?

Comment: Cant you make a library out of all these obj files and add in the linking dependency this library ? i think that's how its done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upon inspection of Microsoft.CppBuild.targets, I found that .obj files for projects with `UseLibraryDependencyInputs` set to true, which corresponds to checking 'use Library Dependency Inputs' in VS, are included only if the project is a StaticLibrary.

A quick and dirty way around this then is to override the Task `ResolvedLinkObjs` inside the .vcxproj, with slight modifications.

Testing this out, I was able to link all the .obj files from the projects I referenced.

I changed the `ItemName` of the `TargetOutputs` MSBuild task output to `"ProjectReferenceToLink"` and added `ConfigurationType=StaticLibrary` to the passed `Propertie`s. The side-effects of treating the .exe project as a `StaticLibrary` while calling this target aren't immediately obvious, but I haven't noticed anything bad.

```
  <Target Name="ResolvedLinkObjs" DependsOnTargets="$(CommonBuildOnlyTargets)">
    <MSBuild Projects="@(_MSBuildProjectReferenceExistent)"
             Targets="GetResolvedLinkObjs"
             BuildInParallel="$(BuildInParallel)"
             Properties="%(_MSBuildProjectReferenceExistent.SetConfiguration); %(_MSBuildProjectReferenceExistent.SetPlatform); ConfigurationType=StaticLibrary"
             Condition="'%(_MSBuildProjectReferenceExistent.Extension)' == '.vcxproj' and '@(ProjectReferenceWithConfiguration)' != '' and '@(_MSBuildProjectReferenceExistent)' != ''"
             ContinueOnError="!$(BuildingProject)"
             RemoveProperties="%(_MSBuildProjectReferenceExistent.GlobalPropertiesToRemove)">
      <Output TaskParameter="TargetOutputs" ItemName="ProjectReferenceToLink" />
    </MSBuild>
  </Target>
```

This can easily be modified to just grab the .objs from one project. A cleaner method would also probably involve not overriding a built-in Target like this but instead inserting it into to the chain.

Answer (score 0):

Need more information really.

But I'll take a stab at a solution.

Create a library containing the functionality required by the executable and the unit tests.

So you end up with a library and  two executables, one being your product and another executable containing your unit tests?

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, but this is the obvious solution I myself was trying to avoid in the first place. It's far more work and is far riskier then just hardcoding .obj files to link.